# rails link_to sends get instead of post

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have some links which I want to send POST request but they are sending get

```
<p class="tags">
  <% tags.keys.each do |key| %>
    <% if tags[key] == 1 %>
      <%= link_to by_tag_media_path(:tag => key), :remote => true, :method => :post do %>
        <span class="font-18"><%= key %></span>
      <% end %>
    <% elsif tags[key] == 2 %>
      <%= link_to by_tag_media_path(:tag => key), :remote => true, :method => :post do %>
        <span class="font-24"><%= key %></span>
      <% end %>
    <% elsif tags[key] == 3 %>
      <%= link_to by_tag_media_path(:tag => key), :remote => true, :method => :post do %>
        <span class="font-36"><%= key %></span>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

this links are in the partial named _tags.html.erb and on the index.html.erb page where is the partial call I have this js code:

```
function apply_filters(load_more){
          var params = "";

          $("a.selected").each(function(i, obj){
            params += $(this).text() + "/"
          });

          $("a.type_class").each(function(i, obj){
            params += $(this).text() + "/";
          });

          if(load_more){
            $.post("/media/filtered", {filters: params, load_more: true});
          } else {
            $.post("/media/filtered", {filters: params});
          }
        }

        $("#filtered_media_path").click(function(){
          apply_filters(true);
        });
```

when this js code is called the I re-render the _tags.html.erb partial and links are working ok (sends POST) but when initially page is rendered they send GET request. The html code after rendering is the same in both cases.

partial class form index page:

```
<span id="cards">
    <%= render :partial => "media_cards", :locals => {:media_cards => @media_cards, :tags => @tags, :featured_cards => @featured_cards} %>
</span>
```

and the media_cards partial:

```
 <div class="card media-card search hide-for-mobile">
    <input type="text" name="search-value" id="search_value"/>

    <span id="tags">
      <%= render :partial => "tags", :locals => {:tags => tags} %>
    </span>
  </div>
```

by_tags.js.erb:

```
$("#cards").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'media_cards', :locals => {:media_cards => @media_cards, :tags => @tags, :featured_cards => @featured_cards}) %>");
```

the generated html looks like:

```
<a href="/media/by_tag?tag=test" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">
        <span class="font-36">test</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you show the defined resource in routes.rb?

Answer (score 0):

Here is link_to protype

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```

What you are doing is passing wrong parameters
so change your code

```
link_to("some text", by_tag_media_path(:tag => key),  :remote => true, :method => :post)
```

Comment: I tried your syntax before but have the same result, I don't see what is incorrect in my code, you can use the link_to with a block that's what I'm doing here and the links works after the js code is called and the partial re-renders, it's the same code for the links and in one case it works in other no

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a read at this. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
It has helped me a lot of times.